# BackPack for Laravel: Display two fields with same name

Tags: php, laravel, crud, laravel-backpack

### What I have:

Tables in DB:

```php
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('primary_person');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('secondary_person');
});
```

```php
Schema::create('persons', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('first_name', 255);
    $table->string('last_name', 255);
});
```

Model:

```php
class Order extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;

    protected $table = 'orders';
    protected $fillable = [
        'primary_person',
        'secondary_person',
    ];

    public function primaryPerson()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Person::class, 'id', 'primary_person');
    }

    public function secondaryPerson()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Person::class, 'id', 'secondary_person');
    }
}
```

### What need to do:

On page *edit order* I want to display information about two persons:

- First name of Primary person
- Last name of Primary person
- First name of Secondary person
- Last name of Secondary person

### What I did:

In OrderCrudController.php added:

```php
$this->crud->addFields([
    [
       'label' => 'First Name of Primary person',
       'type' => 'text',
       'name' => 'first_name',
       'entity' => 'primaryPerson',
       'model' => 'App\Models\Person',
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Last Name of Primary person',
        'type' => 'text',
        'name' => 'last_name',
        'entity' => 'primaryPerson',
        'model' => 'App\Models\Person',
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'First Name of Secondary person',
        'type' => 'text',
        'name' => 'first_name',
        'entity' => 'secondaryPerson',
        'model' => 'App\Models\Person',
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Last Name of Secondary person',
        'type' => 'text',
        'name' => 'last_name',
        'entity' => 'secondaryPerson',
        'model' => 'App\Models\Person',
    ]
]);
```

### What I receive:

Only latest two fields (secondary person information).

[image]

### What I want to see

[image]

### The main problem:

I couldn't display Fields with the same *"name"*, because *"name"* - the attribute (column in the database), which will also become the name of the input.
In Columns this situation handled with *"key"* attribute. **But in Fields it doesn't work.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution – use accessors and mutators (many thanks to @tabacitu).
https://dev.to/sergunik/how-to-display-two-fields-with-same-name-in-backpack-for-laravel-8b1

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you cannot have two fields with the same name. In columns it's possible using the `key` attribute, but as you've mentioned, in the create/update forms it's a problem because of how HTML forms work: only the last input's value will be passed to PHP, to be stored in the database.

I recommend you work around this using [accessors & mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators). You can name the second field something else, even if that column does not exist in the database. Then just have a ```setSecondFirstName($value)```` method inside your Model that takes that value and saves it however you want.

Hope it helps.